# Query enum value from DB in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, enums

My Appointment database has `Appointment ID, Status(enum type), Student` as column values.

This is the `Status` enum:

```
 public enum StatusType
{
    Pending,
    Approved,
    Cancelled
}
```

I need to query the list of rows in the db(appointments) where `Status` column is set to `'Pending'` and pass it to a list variable.

How do I do that in Visual Studio using C#?

```
IEnumerable<Appointment> AppQuery = from appointment in _appointmentData.GetAll()
                                            where appointment.Status???? 
                                            select appointment;
```

Note: `_appointmentData.GetAll()` lists the entire rows in the db.

Comment: Have you tried `where appointment.Status == StatusType.Pending`

Comment: what is the datatype of status in your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends a bit on what gets stored in your database, but what about using `.Equals`:

```
IEnumerable<Appointment> AppQuery = from appointment in _appointmentData.GetAll()
       where appointment.Status.Equals(StatusType.Pending)
       select appointment;
```